# Why doesn't the paragraph show?

Tags: javascript, onload

I am learning the behavior of an onload and onresize events on a body element that contains a paragraph. The paragraph in the body element does not appear, but the onload message does. Does the onload event prevent the paragraph from being displayed for some reason?

I deleted the code inside the body tag and the paragraph is displayed. I put it back and the paragraph is not displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      function message(msg) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = msg + " EVENT";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="output" onload="message('LOAD')" onresize="message('RESIZE')">
    <p>
      Hover over an image below to display here.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the onload and onresize messages to be displayed above the paragraph text.

Comment: Use event listeners, it's better practice.

Comment: Setting .innerHTML completely replaces the content of body with whatever you set it to, including your paragraph text.

Comment: you are setting the `innerHTML` of the body tag. it removes everything.

Comment: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = msg + " EVENT";` you're replacing the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

By doing `body.innerHTML = text` you are setting the `innerHTML` (which includes everything inside the `body` tag) to be that text only ... you will get something like this :

```
<body>LOAD EVENT</body>
```

instead you should add that text to your existing content like  :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      function message(msg) {
        var body = document.getElementById("output")
        body.innerHTML += msg + " EVENT";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="output" onload="message('LOAD')" onresize="message('RESIZE')">
    <p>
      Hover over an image below to display here.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```